# A cochain-level Adem relation?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, steenrod-algebra

The original paper on Steenrod squares, [Steenrod's "Products of cocycles and extensions of mappings", 1947](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969172), uses an explicit combinatorial formula for the squares in terms of simplicial cochains: given a simplicial cochain $\alpha$ on some simplicial set, Steenrod defines a cochain $\mathrm{Sq}^i\alpha$; if $\alpha$ is a cocycle, so is $\mathrm{Sq}^i\alpha$, and the cohomology class of $\mathrm{Sq}^i\alpha$ only depends on that of $\alpha$, and so $\mathrm{Sq}^i$ descends to a (linear!) map on cohomology. (In general, $\mathrm{Sq}^i$ is not linear on cochains and does not commute with $\mathrm d$, so this is a nontrivial statement. But it is not too hard to find an operation that agrees with $\mathrm{Sq}^i$ on cocycles and that does commute with $\mathrm d$, and its failure to be linear, it is not hard to show, is a total derivative.) (Steenrod makes his definition with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients, but I will only care about $\mathbb Z/2$ coefficients, and so assume that throughout.)

The well-known [Adem relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_algebra#Adem_relations), due originally to [Adem,  "The iteration of the Steenrod squares in algebraic topology", 1952](https://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.38.8.720) and beautifully explained by [Bullett and Macdonald, "On the Adem relations", 1982](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(82)90015-5), are relations of the form $0 = \sum_{\text{certain pairs }(i,j)} \mathrm{Sq}^i \mathrm{Sq}^j$ that hold in cohomology. The first few are
 $\mathrm{Sq}^1 \mathrm{Sq}^1 = 0$, $\mathrm{Sq}^1\mathrm{Sq}^2 = \mathrm{Sq}^3 \mathrm{Sq}^0$, $\mathrm{Sq}^1 \mathrm{Sq}^3 = 0$, $\mathrm{Sq}^3 \mathrm{Sq}^1 = \mathrm{Sq}^2 \mathrm{Sq}^2$, ...

At the cochain level, these relations do not hold on the nose. The fact that they hold on cohomology just says that, if $\alpha$ is a cocycle, then $\sum_{\text{certain pairs }(i,j)} \mathrm{Sq}^i (\mathrm{Sq}^j(\alpha))$ is a coboundary, which of course depends on $\alpha$ (and on the particular relation in question).

Is there a combinatorial formula (like the one Steenrod gives for $\mathrm{Sq}^i$) that takes in $\alpha$ a cocycle and produces a primitive for $\sum_{\text{certain pairs }(i,j)} \mathrm{Sq}^i (\mathrm{Sq}^j(\alpha))$? Where can I find it? I care only about the early Adem relations up to $\mathrm{Sq}^3\mathrm{Sq}^1 = \mathrm{Sq}^2\mathrm{Sq}^2$.

A related question was asked by [Kapustin](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/252018/). Note that I am not after more categorical descriptions of the Adem relations and the Steenrod squares like those available in the many excellent answers to [this old MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/461/) — I really do want a combinatorial description that fits into the framework of Steenrod's original paper.

Comment: I should remark that, as Bullet and Macdonald explain, the Squares have to do with the symmetric group $S_2$ action on $X \to X \times X$, and the Adem relation has to do with a homotopy between maps $X \to X^{\times 4}$ having to do with the fact that different embeddings of the dihedral group $D_8$ into $S_4$ are conjugate. Surely this geometric picture can be used to produce the primitives I am looking for. But I find I am not sufficient combinatorially adept to do it, so I am hoping someone else has.

Comment: The earliest study of cochain level operations that I am aware of is by [Kristensen and Madsen](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/surgery/uicc/krismads.pdf). Our work with Baues might be also relevant, it is in his book on the secondary Steenrod algebra. This is however not so directly based on the cochain approach.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks! Kritensen+Madsen's work is very helpful for me.

Comment: I think that the sequence operad from McClure-Smith can be used to produce explicit reasons why the Adem relations hold in cohomology. I did this for a simple Cartan-relation in small degrees by hand (and afterwards I thought it would be nice if this was written up somewhere and stopped thinking about it). https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268031/cartan-formula-for-steenrod-square-on-cocycles?rq=1 seems related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Explicit homotopies for a cochain-level Adem relation were first worked out in:

[Greg Brumfiel, Anibal M. Medina-Mardones, John Morgan. A Cochain Level Proof of Adem Relations in the Mod 2 Steenrod Algebra. 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.09354)

The odd-prime case is still open.

Answer (score 7):

The following article might be relevant.  This is the review I wrote for it a number of years ago.

MR1622630 (99h:55027) Reviewed
Real, Pedro(E-SEVLIS-AM1)
On the computability of the Steenrod squares. (English, Italian summary)
Ann. Univ. Ferrara Sez. VII (N.S.) 42 (1996), 57–63 (1998).
55S05 (55S10)

Let $C_∗(X)$ denote the normalized chains on a simplicial set $X$. The Eilenberg-Zilber theorem can be proved using very explicit operators $AW:C_∗(X×Y) \rightarrow C_∗(X)\otimes C_∗(Y)$, $EM:C_∗(X)\otimes C_∗(Y) \rightarrow C_∗(X×Y)$, and $SHI:C_∗(X×Y)→C_{∗+1}(X×Y)$. The contracting homotopy SHI is least familiar, but like EM it involves an explicit summation over shuffles.
   The author gives an explicit and clean cochain level formula for the mod 2 Steenrod operation $Sq^i$ in terms of AW and SHI. Like SHI, it is exponential in terms of computational complexity.
   {Reviewer's remark: The author systematically uses the word "idempotent'' where he seems to mean "involution''.}